# how to get child single records based on multiple condition having multiple child nodes c# linq or xpath

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

```
 var records = (from root in myxmlDoc.Descendants("Root")
                from nts in root.Elements("nts")
                select new
                {
                    Id = (nts.Elements("Id").Any() == true) ? (nts.Element("Id").Value) : string.Empty,
                    Name = (nts.Elements("Name").Any() == true) ? (nts.Element("Name").Value) : string.Empty,
                }).ToList();
```

How can i achive this with `<Round>` here `<Round>` elements will be multiple times not fixed count ans also have to take records near to dynamic date

```
<Root>
    <nts>
     <Id>A</Id>
     <Name>Rahul</Name>
     <Round>
       <prodDate>2016-03-31</prodDate>
       <roundDue>0.00</roundDue>
     </Round>
     <Round>
       <prodDate>2016-04-01</prodDate>
       <roundDue>400.00</roundDue>
     </Round>
     <Round>
       <prodDate>2016-05-01</prodDate>
       <roundDue>300.00</roundDue>
     </Round>
     <Round>
       <prodDate>2016-08-06</prodDate>
       <roundDue>100.00</roundDue>
     </Round>
     <nts>
     </Root>
```

I want take single `<Round>` record from multiple `<Round>` element based on following criteria

1. 1) prodDate less than dynamicDate i.e : 2016-09-29 and roundDue > 0 
   Note:  `<Round>` record must be latest record less than of dynamicDate
   i.e 2016-09-29

Expected Result :

```
ID : A;
Name : Rahul
prodDate : 2016-08-06
roundDue : 100.00
```

here prodDate must be latest nearer date of dynamicDate i.e 2016-09-29

Comment: What do you have that doesn't work?

Comment: It sounds like you have two actual *filters* (date less than 2016-09-29, and roundDue greater than 0), and then an ordering (by date, descending). You can then take the first result from that ordered result set.

Comment: i have pasted my code i dont have any idea how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            //Note : new DataTime gives a date of 1/1/1900.  Any valid date should be much closer to actual compare date
            var results = doc.Descendants("nts").Select(x => new
            {
                id = (string)x.Element("Id"),
                name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                round = x.Elements("Round").Select(y => new { prodDate = (object)y.Element("prodDate") == null ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)y.Element("prodDate") , roundDue = (decimal)y.Element("roundDue") })
                   .Where(y => y.roundDue > 0 && y.prodDate < DateTime.Now).OrderBy(y => DateTime.Now - y.prodDate).FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here you have not used dynamicDate i.e 2016-09-29 (this will chnage any time it is dynamic ) and  prodDate must be closest to dynamic date  2016-09-29

Comment: i tried this : but now but not getting value of roundDue  id = (string)x.Element("Id"),
                name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                round = x.Elements("Round").Select(y => new {prodDate = (DateTime)y.Element("prodDate"), roundDue = (decimal)y.Element("roundDue")})
                   .Where(y=>y.roundDue >0 && y.prodDate < DateTime.Now).Max(y=> y.prodDate)
            }).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: facing issue while <prodDate> element missing how to validate if this element not found itshould return null  or by pass the result

Comment: I modified code to test for null.  Same may need to be done for roundDue.  See my comment in the modified code.

Comment: getting this error {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element"}  .

Comment: Are you using the latest code I posted? A DateTime cannot be null so I'm using new DateTime which give a date of 1/1/1900.  I originall was testing for null be realized the a DateTime cannot be null.  I also cast the element of an object to avoid other errors.  I don't have an object called 'element' so I'm not sure if my code is giving the error.